# Why do OnClientConnect and OnClientError events not fire for TServerSocket in blocking mode

Tags: c++, sockets, c++builder, c++builder-xe

I am using Embarcadero RAD studio C++ builder XE to create a C++ application. The application uses a dynamically created `TServerSocket` component in blocking mode. I create a class derived from `TServerClientThread` which provides a custom `ClientExecute()` method. This class is created via the `TServerSocket` event handler `OnGetThread` which I have implemented. I assign event handlers for `OnAccept`, `OnClientConnect`, `OnClientDisconnect` and `OnClientError`. Inside my thread class I use `TWinSocketStream` class to read and write from the socket connection.

I use a custom written class (derived from `TComponent`) that creates the `TServerSocket` and the event handlers I assign are member functions of this class.

My `OnAccept` and `OnClientDisconnect` events fire but neither of the `OnClientConnect` and `OnClientError` events fire ever. Is this normal behaviour for this component? Everything I have read about this component suggests that ALL events will fire for `TServerSocket` in blocking mode and I simply cannot understand why these events will not fire. Is there anything further I am required to do or these events just not work in blocking mode? Is it possible that using the `TServerSocket` instance as a member of another `TComponent` derived class is causing some problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnClientConnect` event is triggered by the `TServerClientWinSocket` constructor.  A `TServerClientWinSocket` object is constructed immediately after the `OnGetSocket` event is called when a new client socket is accepted by WinSock, and right before the `OnAccept` and `OnGetThread` events are called.  So the only possible way that `OnClientConnect` would not be called is if you do not actually have a handler assigned to it.

`OnClientError` is called during non-blocking socket failures, and by `TCustomWinSocket.SendStream()`, `TCustomWinSocket.SendBuf()`, and `TCustomWinSocket.ReceiveBuf()`.  If you use `TWinSocketStream` instead for your I/O, none of those methods are called by it.  It raises `ESocketError` exceptions on failure instead.  If you do not catch those exceptions, the calling `TServerClientThread`  will simply terminate itself (after passing the exception to the main thread for handling).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have a OnClientConnect handler assigned, but I have not written an `OnGetSocket` handler as I understood that it is not essential. I do have an `OnGetThread` handler but is the absence of `OnGetSocket` handler a possible reason that my event does not fire?

Comment: `OnGetSocket` is optional, and has no effect whatsoever on `OnClientConnect` being called or not. If you have a handler assigned to `OnClientConnect` then it should be getting called, unless `TServerSocket` in 2010/XE has a bug that is not in other versions. I have never had any problem with `OnClientConnect` being called correctly. I suggest you enable debug libraries in your Project Options so you can step into TServerSocket's source code in `ScktComp.pas` and find out why `TServerClientWinSocket.Create()` is not calling `OnClientConnect` when called by  `TServerWinSocket.GetClientSocket()`.

Comment: I will try what you suggest. Thankyou for your help.